# Is there a way to delete sheets that are after a specific index/location?

Tags: excel, vba

Hoping to programmatically delete all sheets that are after the Xth spreadsheet, with the order done by how I see it visually in Excel (first being the very left spreadsheet). So if I want to delete anything after the 4th spreadsheet, I want to delete the 5th sheet and everything after it.

Looks like the `Sheets` object doesn't have an index or location type of object. I'm thinking of an alternative solution of creating an array of the names of the first 4 spreadsheets and looping through all the names of the spreadsheets and checking if they are not in the array to delete, but this will likely take longer than checking index location.

Is there a way to do this without that loop?

Comment: It's probably much safer to code in the 4 spreadsheets you want to preserve, then loop and delete the rest. It's a fairly simple loop - you're only checking the name - and much harder for end-users to screw up.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you're looking for.

```
If Sheets.Count >= 5 Then
    For sht = Sheets.Count To 5 Step -1
        'If Sheets(sht).Name = "some name" Then   '''USE THIS IF YOU KNOW THE SHEET NAMES
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Sheets(sht).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        'End If
    Next
End If
```